# Batch File Run Hotkey Fn and F8?

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey, hotkeys, sendkeys

I have a MSI X370 Laptop and the WiFi and camera services are always turned off. The shortcut for turning the WiFi on is <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> while camera is <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. When I checked the Services (Local), the WLAN AutoConfig is running and it's startup type is Automatic.

My solution for now is to create a batch file that will run the keyboard commands every I turn on the Laptop.

I tried researching and found a solution like:
Example: execute a hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>)

1. Create a vbs script

   Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   WshShell.SendKeys "^%1"
2. Create a batch file and put it on startup folder

   wscript "sendkey.vbs"

The code is pretty easy but my problem is that I don't know what is the code for <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> keyboard keys.

Is it possible?

Comment: Fn keys are NOT part of windows but part of hardware. You cannot send Fn keys.

Comment: @Noodles is there any solution?

Comment: The codes of the keys you want are `{F8}` and `{F6}`. See the table at [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Descibe your Fn key. Are you doing a computer manufacturer thing. On my HP the F keys do computer manufacturer things (dim display etc) and Fn turns them into windows F keys. On my desktop the Fn keys swaps between Windows appkeys (things like Cut/Copy/Paste) and Windows F keys. You can't simulate manufacturers keys.

Comment: @Noodles: In Laptop computers the functions keys alone do hardware related things and the way to send a FN key to Windows is pressing the `FN` key first and then the desired `F#` key, that is _precisely_ what the OP describe in the question!

Comment: You describe my laptop, not all laptops.

Comment: @NoodlesWhat I wanted to do is to turn on the wifi by pressing FN + F8 but I don't want to do it every time I turn on my computer so I wanted to create a batch file to autorun it

Comment: @FewFlyBy: Just try it: `WshShell.SendKeys "{F8}{F6}"`

Comment: @Aacini - That's just F8 and F6 by themselves; the documentation says nothing about the Fn key.

Comment: @SomethingDark: The keyboard layout of Fn+F# to _send_ a FN key in Laptops have several years, so I _assumed_ that the OP's Laptop have the same layout. However, this discussion is totally useless because just a test can confirm or deny any _hypotesis_ about this point.

Comment: The issue is that I don't have a battery for my laptop for now so I'm using it while plugged in. So I guess whenever I turn it off, the BIOS resets? Or the hardware functionalities resets?

Comment: Probably. You get asked questions but don't answer them.